# Can C++ attributes be used to replace OpenMP pragmas?

Tags: c++, openmp

C++ attributes provide a convenient and standardized way to markup code with extra information to give to the compiler and/or other tools.

Using OpenMP involves adding a lot of `#pragma omp...` lines into the source (such as to mark a loop for parallel processing).  These `#pragma` lines seem to be excellent candidates for a facility such as generalized attributes.

For example, `#pragma omp parallel for` might become `[[omp::parallel(for)]]`.

The often inaccurate cppreference.com uses such an attribute as an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), which confirms it has at least been considered (by someone).

Is there a mapping of OpenMP pragmas to C++ attributes currently available and supported by any/all of the major compilers?  If not, are there any plans underway to create one?

Comment: Just mentioning: http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#attributes

Comment: Perhaps [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) could switch from Bjarne's optimistic `[[omp::parallel()]]` to something that is actually used, like `[[rpr::kernel, rpr::farm(4,ordered), rpr::in(A,C), rpr::out(A,B), rpr::target(cpu,gpu)]]`

Comment: I don't see how having some code inserted right in the middle of a `for` construct is more convenient than a separate **standardised** pragma directive that can easily be ignored or disabled by commenting it out. But you are free to contact the [OpenMP ARB](http://openmp.org/wp/about-openmp/) and ask them to include the new syntax. Some of them even lurk here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HristoIliev Attributes solve some issues related to lambdas that cannot be solved with pragmas.  In any case, there are OpenMP ARB members thinking about this already.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a possibility and it's even something the OpenMP language committee is looking at. Take a look at OpenMP Technical Report 8 (https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-TR8.pdf) page 36, where a syntax for using OpenMP via attributes is proposed. Inclusion in TR8 doesn't guarantee its inclusion in version 5.1, but it shows that it's being discussed. This syntax is largely based on the work done in the original proposal for C++ attributes.

If you have specific feedback on this, I'd encourage you to provide feedback on this via the OpenMP forum (http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=26).